# In a semi-regular polyhedron, why does a polygon with odd sides (e.g. a triangle) have to be surrounded by polygons of the same type (e.g. squares)?

Tags: polyhedra, combinatorial-designs

In a semi-regular polyhedron with 4 faces meeting at each vertex, why does a polygon with an odd number of sides (such as a triangle) have to be surrounded by polygons of the same type (e.g. squares)?

(Each vertex of a semi-regular polyhedron has the same arrangement of polygons around it.)

Comment: As noted in [Wikipedia's "Semiregular polyhedron" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_polyhedron), the term is used in different ways by different authors. Please provide the definition you're using. (Include context and clarifications in the body of the question itself. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Answer (score 1):

In a semi-regular polyhedron every vertex ought be equivalent.

If you'd attach to say a triangle the polygons A, A, B, then there would be a vertex (3, A, ..., A) and 2 vertices (3, A, ..., B).

If you'd attach polygons A, B, C, then you'll get the 3 vertices (3, A, ..., B), (3, A, ..., C), (3, B, ..., C).

Thence the only possibility indeed would be to have all 3 adjacent polygons the same, as only then all vertices would look like (3, A, ..., A).

--- rk